# Touchlistener on widget ?

Tags: android, android-widget

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[]  appWidgetIds) {        
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
       int imageNum = (new java.util.Random().nextInt(IMAGES.length));
       RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
       remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, IMAGES[imageNum]);
       appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteView);
    }
}
```

I want use touchListener here on widget so I can change photos. What I should I call or write for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function **setonClickPendingIntent** on **remoteView** and provide the id of image/button. so that the pending intent will be launched when you click that button.

For example:

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(/*Input Arguments*/);
remoteView.setonClickPendingIntent(R.id.image,pintent);
```

Now as we use **PendingIntent.getBroadcast** to create our pending intent, when it will be launched it will be same like **SendBroadcast** so we have to implement a **onReceive** now.

Now Simply put your on Click Logic in onReceive.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks my friends, for help, That's exactly what I need, it work's fine.